# HTML Polyglot Markup served as text/html+xml

Tags: html, content-type, polyglot-markup

The question is simple:
Can Polyglot Markup be "served" with the `content-type: text/html+xml; charset=utf-8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any content can be served with any content type. What the receiver makes of it is another matter.

`text/html+xml` is not [a registered MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html) although browsers should treat it as XML according to [the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml)

> When a document is transmitted with an XML MIME type, such as
>   application/xhtml+xml, then it is treated as an XML document by Web
>   browsers, to be parsed by an XML processor.

[and](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/infrastructure.html#xml-mime-type)

> The term XML MIME type is used to refer to the MIME types text/xml,
>   application/xml, and any MIME type whose subtype ends with the four
>   characters "+xml". [RFC3023]

The real question is why would you want to do this when there are registered MIME types available for the purpose?

Comment: Yes. To further qualify the bit about "What the receiver makes of it is another matter", I did a little test and none of the browsers I've tried would display the file; they all said "unknown filetype" and wanted to save it to disk instead.

Comment: @MrLister - Right, thanks. Of course, once the content has been passed off to the XML parser, what the browser does with the content and content type is outside the scope of any html spec, and the browser can treat it as it likes.